# Set CSS from Google Sheet data

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a customisable web app, and I want to be able to specify the app colours from a google sheet. I can do it as demonstrated below, but I'm hoping someone knows a better way so I can get the correct colour to display from the first load, not having to wait for javascript to run.

As a basic example, for setting the background colour I have a google sheet with the background colour in hex in cell "B1" on sheet "Data", and then the apps script attached to the sheet has 4 files: Code.gs, page.html, page-css.html and page-js.html.

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
 
  const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");  
  return html.evaluate();
  
}

function getColours(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  const colourData = {"background": dataSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue()};
  return colourData;
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <?!= include("page-js"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

page-css.html:

```
<style>
  :root{
    --background: black;
    --text: white;
  
  }

  .container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--background);
    color:var(--text);
  }

</style>
```

page-js.html:

```
<script>
  var r = document.querySelector(":root");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setColours).getColours();

  function setColours(colourData){
    r.style.setProperty("--background", colourData.background);
  }
</script>
```

I would be grateful if anyone can suggest a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a scriptlet to the CSS.

FROM:

```
--background: black;
```

TO:

```
--background: <?!= getColours(); ?>
```

Also change your `include` function.

```
function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate().getContent();
}
```

Style Code:

```
<style>
  :root{
    --background: <?!= getColours(); ?>;
    --text: white;
  
  }

  .container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--background);
    color:var(--text);
  }

</style>
```

GS function

```
function getColours(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var colourData = dataSheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();

  if (!colourData) {
    colourData = "black";
  }

  return colourData;
}
```

You should be able to remove the code that runs in the script tag.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I made the changes you outlined above, but if I remove the code that runs in the script tag, then the background colour doesn't get set.  I also tried, in addition to your suggestions, changing 'getColours()' to return just the background colour code rather than returning the object that contained that code, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I updated the answer to show the `getColours` function that returns a default of "black".